# Getting watershed area corresponding to each erosion severity class for each slope class in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, slope, surface

I’m new to this.

I have two (watershed) rasters: soil loss (erosion) by severity; and slope. For each erosion severity class (listed below), I would like to obtain the watershed area that falls under each slope class (listed below).

I’m using ArcMap 10.7 and used the Reclassify tool to obtain rasters with the appropriate range (1-5) for both erosion severity and slope. How should I then proceed?

**Erosion severity (t/ha/yr)**

- Mild (0-12)
- Moderate (12-35)
- Strong (35-50)
- Very strong (50-100)
- Extreme (> 100)

**Slope (%)**

- 0-10
- 10-20
- 20-30
- 30-40
- Greater than 40

Answer (score 0):

Ensure both rasters are integer, you could use reclassify to recode them and then use the [tabulate area](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) tool.

Comment: Repeat for each individual catchment?

Comment: @Hornbydd My concern is how to associate the two reclassified rasters to solve my problem. For instance, what should I do to extract the area with mild erosion severity that corresponds to the <12%, 12-35%,..., slope classes? I then repeat the process for the other (moderate, high, very high, and extreme) severity classes. Thanks!

Comment: As simple model exploding out the pixels by severity into separate datasets that then feed into the tabulate area tool will do it. Suggest you look at model builder iterators?